# Matter generation during cosmic inflation (Hawking radiation like...)

Tags: big-bang, cosmological-inflation, hawking-radiation

Is there any estimation of how much of the matter in the observable universe was not created during the big bang, but later during cosmic inflation?

My thought is as follows: Suppose we are in the area of cosmic inflation. Then virtual matter / antimatter particles from the quantum vacuum are sometimes "ripped apart" by the superluminal expansion of the space between them. Hence they can not recombine and are therefore real particles now. Right?

A mechanism similar to Hawkings radiation (thought of). Shouldn't this contribute to the overall amount of particles in the universe? I mean the antimatter part of this will innihilate with surrounding matter soon but the matter part will stay to exist. Or not?

Are there any estimations of the overall percentage of this "inflation time matter" vs. previously generated matter?

Comment: Thinking about it, answering this question might not only need a quantum theory of gravitation (as with Hawkings radiation) but moreover a quantum theory of dark energy or whatever the driving force of cosmic inflation actually was. So an answer can not really be expected... But still it is interesting to think that cosmic inflation might have contributed to the amount of matter in the universe.

Comment: One of the motivations for using a scalar field to drive inflation is that the inflaton field can decay into the standard model particles at the end of inflation.